# Colorizing greyscale images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm looking for a *trained* colorization model (wlnet file) that is available to download and immediate use in 11.2.  Checking the 21 currently existing NetModels:

```
all = Flatten[ResourceSearch /@ {"model", "net", "trained"}];
netmodels = DeleteCases[all, x_ /; FreeQ[x, "NeuralNet", \[Infinity]]];
Length[netmodels]
```

shows such a model it's not available yet as a NetModel[].

**Details**

Found an *unusable* example (no data/training code and uses deprecated code) [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/884348), might be a starting point.

Comment: You can use GAN to train a model or using API from http://demos.algorithmia.com/colorize-photos/

Comment: The GAN model can refer pix2pix model of http://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter14_generative-adversarial-networks/pixel2pixel.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two colorization nets available right now: `NetModel["ColorNet Image Colorization Trained on Places Data (Raw Model)"]` and `NetModel["ColorNet Image Colorization Trained on ImageNet Competition Data (Raw Model)"]`. For usage, see [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ColorNet-Image-Colorization-Trained-on-Places-Data-Raw-Model) and [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ColorNet-Image-Colorization-Trained-on-ImageNet-Competition-Data-Raw-Model_1).

Comment: Wow,really cooooooool. Thank you!!!

Comment: But could you give examples about how to train the Model in the website?

Comment: @partida: showing how to train would make it way harder for us to add models. Many models have been trained for days/weeks, often using datasets that are not generally available, and if they are available, they are often massive requiring careful out-of-core processing and pre-processing. It would be very hard for us to verify that our training instructions result in a similar model to the pretrained one. If you want to reproduce the training, you will need to read the reference paper.

Comment: what a pity....Anyway thank you for taking so many amazing models to us